# MySql Query: Left Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new Sql Queries.I wanted to make a table from difference of two tables.
Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `question` WHERE `relatedFields` = 'Math' LEFT JOIN  `answer` ON `question`.ques = `answer`.ques where `answer`.TeacherNumber=1111111111
```

Please help.

Comment: If you need the where clause that should be always after the join clause and where makes a left join to an inner join. You need to provide some sample data and expected result out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the first `WHERE` clause to the end, and move that other where condition to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `question`
  LEFT JOIN  `answer` ON `question`.ques = `answer`.ques
     and `answer`.TeacherNumber=1111111111
where `question`.relatedFields = 'Math'
```

Alternative syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (select * from `question` WHERE `relatedFields` = 'Math') as q
LEFT JOIN
    (select * from `answer` where TeacherNumber = 1111111111) as a
  ON q.ques = a.ques
```

Answer (score 1):

This post will help you to understand better the joins. It help me too.

[Explanation about Joins click here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

[image]